# React context values from consumer are always their initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am using React context to pass down data, following the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts), however I am stuck with the initial value and am not sure what I did wrong.

This is what my context file looks like:

```js
export const ItemsContext = createContext([]);
ItemsContext.displayName = 'Items';


export const ItemsProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const setData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setItems(await getItemsApiCall());
        setLoading(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setData();
    }, []);

    console.warn('Items:', items); // This shows the expected values when using the provider
    return (
        <ItemsContext.Provider value={{ items, loading }}>
            {children}
        </ItemsContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Now, I want to feed in those items into my app in the relevant components. I am doing the following:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <ItemsContext.Consumer>
            {(items) => {
                console.warn('items?', items); // Is always the initial value of "[]"
                return (<div>Test</div>);
            }}
        </ItemsContext.Consumer>
    );
}
```

However, as my comment states, `items` will always be empty. On the other hands, if I do just use the `ItemsProvider`, I do get the proper value, but at this point need to access it directly on the app, so the `ItemsContext.Consumer` seems to make more sense.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Edit: A way around it seems to be to wrap the `Consumer` with the `Provider`, but that feels wrong and didn't see that at the docs. Is that perhaps the case?

So essentially, something like this:

```js
const App = () => {
    return (
    <ItemsProvider>
        <ItemsContext.Consumer>
            {(items) => {
                console.warn('items?', items); // Is always the initial value of "[]"
                return (<div>Test</div>);
            }}
        </ItemsContext.Consumer>
    </ItemsProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a `ItemsContext` provider above the `App` component hierarchy,otherwise the default value of the context will be used.
something  in this form:

```
    <ItemsContext.Provider value={...}>
        <App/>
    </ItemsContext.Provider>
```